Sitecore 10.4 Upgrade Launchpad is not updated
We are upgrade the Sitecore from 8.2 to 10.4. We have followed below steps to perform the database upgrade
1. Install Sitecore vanilla 10.4
2. Restore the 8.2 database
3. Run the database scripts Core, master and web database.
4. Pointed the new database in the vanila connectionstring.config
5. On the Sitecore Launchpad, open the Control Panel, in the Database section, click Clean up databases, select all the
databases, and then click Clean.
6. Run the "**Sitecore.UpdateApp.exe clean**"

The issue is the Sitecore launchpad and all the icons image is different is competitively vanilla instance. Attached two image for the reference.
Vanilla Sitecore 10.4 Instance

After upgrade

Still, icons referring to old paths

Is there any other action need to perform, Kindly advise.
Still see the 8.2 refernce in launchpad after run the upgrade scripts, clean database, Sitecore.UpdateApp.exe clean command

Updates
Database query


Are you copying any files from your solution over the top of the vanilla site? Best bet is to inspect the two dashboards and confirm what class or css is causing the header to be red. You can them inspect old vs new css files to see why it is not being applied. This way you can then investigate why that change not applied

Is it something that can help. https://buoctrenmay.com/2022/11/21/sitecore-10-2-0-after-upgrading-from-sitecore-9-0-0-databases-the-launchpad-looks-slight-different-with-fresh-one/

I have changed only connection string of the core, master, security and web database.

Please see updated answer

As described in this article, they are having the same issue, you can download and install this package.
https://gitlab.com/viet.hoang/workshop/-/blob/master/Sitecore%2010.2%20item%20package/Default%20Launchpad%20Item-1.0.zip
And check if this resolves your issue.
Hope this helps.

This package works only for the "Sitecore Experience Platform" text. Still the icons is refereeing old.

Ok so you mean the it resolve the red header? right

Yes, that is resolved

launchpad icon still referring old one.

Check out this blog post as ut seems to have similar issue to what you are describing:
https://buoctrenmay.com/2022/11/21/sitecore-10-2-0-after-upgrading-from-sitecore-9-0-0-databases-the-launchpad-looks-slight-different-with-fresh-one/
Root cause they identified is:

/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad” having old presentation
details

UPDATE 25/10/24
The only reason you can be seeing the old icons, is if you failed to complete step (6) in your list


Run the "Sitecore.UpdateApp.exe clean"


In Sitecore 10.3, the data for all the important sitecore item is read from Items AS Resources (IAR) files. The cleaning process mentioned above deletes all the information from the various DBs, that Sitecore wants to read from the IAR files.
If this step is not completed correctly, the SQL data take priority over the IAR files and overwrites it.
If you take a vanilla Sitecore instance, then run the following SQL you should get zero results returned:
SELECT * FROM [Your_Sitecore_core].[dbo].[SharedFields]
WHERE ItemId = 'F20C2C6D-ACFC-40BA-B560-A8DF0803A85E'

If you then edit that same field via the Sitecore UI, then rerun the query, you will see results are returned.

To test this out, run the above query and see if anything is returned. If so, then the old SQL values are overwriting the IAR values. Run this query:
DELETE FROM [Your_Sitecore_core].[dbo].[SharedFields]
WHERE ItemId = 'F20C2C6D-ACFC-40BA-B560-A8DF0803A85E'

If you check your launchpad, you should then see the correct icon. Meaning that the icon is being read from IAR files.
In summary, in order to correct your installation, you wil need to try rerunning the Sitecore.UpdateApp.exe for the CORE database.

already ran multiple time the Sitecore.UpdateApp.exe clean , core: 0 item(s) it is coming in cmd .

When you run the select query above, does it return any result?

yes, It is return, then i ran the delete query, followed by run the clean cmd.

After running the DELETE query. The SELECT query should then return zero result. If you then recycle the app pool for the CM instance, then the icon should revert to the correct icon. The information for the incorrect icon is coming from that field, so if the query returns zero result, then there is nowhere for the data to come from. It must come from IAR

updated the question

Thanks for the update - I can see you are using the ID from ckhannas answer. This refers to Email Experience Manager (ECM) - which is not visible in my launchpad... Please try doing the same for the ID I originally provided F20C2C6D-ACFC-40BA-B560-A8DF0803A85E then double check the Experience Analytics icon on launchpad

Are you definitely recycling the AppPool? Seems like you might be getting cached result or something? What happens when you run SELECT * FROM [core].[dbo].[SharedFields]
WHERE Value ='Applications/32x32/Stock.png'

I did recylce multiple time, This pbm not only the Experience Analytics icon. issue exist all the icons. if you see th latest updated last image.

@Rameshkumar Please see continued discussion in this chatroom https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/155968/sitecore-10-4-upgrade-launchpad-is-not-updated

In order to fix the issue for launch pad icon, you will need to go the core database and remove the items from there. You can run below query to get those details.
SELECT *
  FROM [Core_DB_Name].[dbo].[SharedFields]
  Where ItemId = '852A679B-FA00-4A6B-BF7A-CBEEDBC576BE' and FieldId = 'D25B56D4-23B6-4462-BE25-B6A6D7F38E13'

In the above query, FieldId is the id of the icon field in the core database. You can replace the ItemID with the ids of the item in the launchpad.

For all the items in the launchpad, you will need to delete those items from the Items and SharedFields table in the core database by running below query.
Delete from [Core_DB_Name].[dbo].[Items]
Where ID = '852A679B-FA00-4A6B-BF7A-CBEEDBC576BE'

Delete from [Core_DB_Name].[dbo].[SharedFields]
Where ItemId = '852A679B-FA00-4A6B-BF7A-CBEEDBC576BE'

Once the delete operation is performed for all the items, you can recycle the app pool. Thereafter, Sitecore will render the icons from the resource files located under the Data\items\core folder in the UpdateAppTool.
Note: The items in the launchpad might got have skipped on UpdateApp tool in case there is any modification made to any of the fields inside them. You can check for them inside the Data\logs folder of the UpdateApp.
Update:
Can you try running below snippet in Powershell to check whether resource file for the launchpad items exist and is not overridden by sql.
$item = Get-Item -Path core: -Query "/sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/Marketing/Forms"
$aItemLocation = $item.Database.DataManager.DataSource.GetItemLocations($item.ID)

#resource file exist
[Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.ItemLocations.AggregatedItemLocationsExtensions]::IsResource($aItemLocation)
# check if the resource file is not getting overridden from sql.
[Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.ItemLocations.AggregatedItemLocationsExtensions]::IsOverridden($aItemLocation)

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

hi, here is not only experience analytics icons all the icons in the sitecore lunchpad.

@Rameshkumar Did you tried to perform the step for one item in the launchpad to delete the items from Items and 'SharedFields` table as mentioned above. Did that worked?

yes, i have perform the delete query. But that is not working as expected.

@Rameshkumar Can you try running above powershell snippet for the items on launchpad and check whether the resource file exist and is not overridden by sql. Also I hope you restarted app pool after deleting items from database.

updated the question

@Rameshkumar did you tried running the powershell script above for one of the items on launchpad..can you please share the output you are getting for the same.

you can try running for the same item on which you have deleted rows from sql table i.e /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons/Marketing/ECM or {852A679B-FA00-4A6B-BF7A-CBEEDBC576BE}

Also can you try once clearing cache on CMS using sitecore/admin/cache.aspx as well.

Tried, not working

@Rameshkumar is it possible to connect over Sitecore slack...
